# Root of the derivative is unique in some intervals

Tags: polynomials

Suppose that $p_n$ is the n-th (real) polynomial, and that it has $n$ simple real roots, let's call them for $x_{n,1}<x_{n,2}<\dots <x_{n,n}$. Then, by Rolle's theorem, $p_n'$ has a real root in each $(x_{n,1},x_{n,2})$, $(x_{n,2},x_{n,3})$, etc. How do you show that this root is unique in these intervals?

Comment: What is the degree of $p_n$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The degree is exactly $n$

Comment: Then what is the degree of $p_n'$ and how many real roots can it have at most?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well, if $p_n$ has degree $n$, so $p_n'$ must be of degree $n-1$. As for the roots, I would say it has at most $n-1$ real roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $p_n'$ had multiple roots in one of the intervals. Then $p_n'$ would have more than $n-1$ roots. But since $p_n'$ has degree $n-1$, it can only have $n-1$ roots, a contradiction.

Comment: This is nice, but how do you know that $p_n'$ can have exactly $n-1$ (real) roots?

Comment: i assumed it was given, since $p_n$ was said to have "$n$ simple real roots", so $p'_n$ must necessarily have at least $n-1$ by Rolle's (as you noted); and we prove here that it can't have more